# DITA to DOCX using plugin com.elovirta.ooxml in DITA OT 1.8.5

Tags: xml, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

Is it possible to convert DITA to DOCX using plugin com.elovirta.ooxml in DITA OT 1.8.5

**input dita map file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "urn:pubid:org:doctypes:dita:map" "map.dtd">
<map>
    <title>This is a test DITA Map</title>
    <topicref href="Bank.dita"/>
</map>
```

**And input dita file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="d63e3" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Student_Notebook">
  <title outputclass="Title">Student Notebook</title>
  <body>
    <section outputclass="Handout"><title>Labs Student Notebook
        1</title><p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Module 1</p><p
        outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Literacy Labs</p><p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Student
        Notebook</p><p outputclass="SC_P_Medium">________________ _______________ _______________
        _______________ </p></section>
  </body>
</topic>
```

After docx transformation runs, i get error log as below:

**docx.convert:**

```
 >[xslt] Processing E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\Test_MERGED.xml to E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\Test_CLEANED.xml
 [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\docx\word\document.flat.xsl
 [xslt] Processing E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\Test_CLEANED.xml to E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\docx\docProps\core.xml
 [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\docx\docProps\core.xsl
 [xslt] Processing E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\Test_CLEANED.xml to E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\docx\word\document.xml
 [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\docx\word\document.xsl
 [xslt] C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\docx\word\document.topic.xsl:22:30: Warning! Stylesheet module file:/C:/DITA-OT/DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED/plugins/com.elovirta.ooxml/docx/word/document.topic.xsl is included or imported more than once. This is permitted, but may lead to errors or unexpected behavior
 [xslt] C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\docx\word\document.topic.xsl:604:47: Fatal Error! No template exists named getVariable
 [xslt] Failed to process E:\Vinod\2017\Jan\4-1\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\Test_CLEANED.xml
```

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\build.xml:44: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-ELED\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\build.xml:74: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
>       at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.readTemplates(TraXLiaison.java:300)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.createTransformer(TraXLiaison.java:317)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:178)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:876)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:414)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at >org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>       at >org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
>   Caused by: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:546)
>       ... 35 more
>   Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
>       at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:97)
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:543)
>
> ### ... 35 more
>
> net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:546)
>       at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.readTemplates(TraXLiaison.java:300)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.createTransformer(TraXLiaison.java:317)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:178)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:876)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:414)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
>   Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
>       at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:97)
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:543)
>       ... 35 more
>
> Total time: 6 seconds
>
> The process finished with exit code: 1

Please assist me.

Comment: No, I think you need DITA 2.x, since one reads *Only latests stable version of DITA-OT is supported.* from https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml

Comment: But i want to convert using DITA 1.8.5 only for resolving that error any suggestions please give me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plugin will not work with `DITA-OT 1.8.5`, which is EOL. Your transformation fails, because the `getVariable` function is not found, which has been introduced with `DITA-OT 2.x`. You should definetely consider migrating your environment to `DITA-OT 2.x`. If you cannot, setup a second toolkit for your `docx` transformations with `com.elovirta.ooxml` and your DITA specializations. You can choose the OT during transformation by setting the `dita.dir` parameter. You can also do this within a build script. It is not worth trying to backport `com.elovirta.ooxml`, you should better spend your resources on upgrading your environment.

Comment: I am having some droughts on this for clarification please provide me your personal mail id.

Comment: After some changes in the xsl of com.elovirta.ooxml plugin is working in DITA OT 1.8.5 but dita file with images its not converting please give me any suggestion on this.